# Format input text with regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I need to format an input text like this: 2342452-1.
After typing seven numbers I need to add a dash (-) and then a number again.
Is there a simple way of doing this in javaScript?

Comment: Yes, using either a search engine like Google or the search field from SO `(:`

Comment: Take a look at [input-mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), this helps me a lot on putting masks in input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length and use `indexOf` to find if this string contains a '-'

```js
function maskinput(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length > 7 && e.target.value.indexOf('-') === -1) {
    let substring1 = e.target.value.slice(0, 7),
      substring2 = e.target.value.slice(7, e.target.value.length);
    e.target.value = substring1 + '-' + substring2;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup='maskinput(event)'>
```